# Get different forms in Django class based view based on condition

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-class-based-views

Suppose I have forms as below :

```
class FormA(models.ModelForm):
    ...
class FormB(models.ModelForm):
  ....
class FormC(models.ModelForm):
 .....
```

Now I want to get the forms in the a class based view as :

Class FormCreateView(CreateView):
        model = User

```
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.user.user_level == 1:
             get FormA
        if self.request.user.user_level == 2:
             get FormB
        if self.request.user.user_level == 3:
             get Formc
        return reverse('xyz')
```

So I have done this way . But the form is not being submitted and it is giving me type error :

```
Exception Value:    
is_valid() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
Exception Location:  
/home/bishwa/PycharmProjects/sharefile/sharefile/users/views.py in post, line 64
```

class

```
class UserCreateView(CreateView):
   model = User
   # form_class = UserCreationForm
   template_name = "users/create_user.html"
   success_url= "/users/create"

   def get_form_class(self):
      if self.request.user.user_level == 1 or self.request.user.user_level == 10:
         # form_class = UserCreationForm
         return  UserCreationForm

      elif self.request.user.user_level == 20:
          # form_class = UserCreationFormCompanyManager
          return  UserCreationFormCompanyManager

      else:
          # form_class = UserCreationFormHomeManager          
          return UserCreationFormHomeManager

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      form = self.get_form_class()
      user_level = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
      # form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
      # if request.method=='POST':
        # form = UserCreationFormCompanyManager(request.POST)
      if user_level == 20:
          if form.is_valid():
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              obj.company = self.request.user.company
              # obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
              print(obj)
              obj.save()
              return obj

      elif user_level == 30:
          # if request.method=='POST':
              # form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              obj = form.save(commit=False)
              obj.company = self.request.user.company
              obj.home = self.request.user.home
              # obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
              print(obj)
              obj.save()  
              return obj
      else:
           # if request.method=='POST':
              # form = UserCreationFormHomeManager(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              # obj.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
              print(obj)
              obj = form.save()
              return obj

    return  HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:create-user'))
```

I have those three form in my `form.py`. When I tried by calling the form by the `request.POST`(i.e the one commented) method form is not being save.

Answer (score 1):

You can use select the form in the [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_form_class) method:

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if self.request.user.user_level == 1:
         return FormA
    elif self.request.user.user_level == 2:
         return FormB
    elif self.request.user.user_level == 3:
         return FormC
    else:
         return DefaultForm
```

Comment: I have tried previously as the method you said but it says we must return an instance i.e `return FormA()` otherwise the `form.is_valid()` method gives the error.

Comment: No, `get_form_class` should return the *class*, as the name suggests. The problem is you are not instantiating the form later e.g. `form = get_form_class()(request.POST)`. Normally the `CreateView` would take care of this for you, but you have lost this functionality because you have overriden `post` incorrectly. Looking at your view, you could remove the form-saving code into `form_valid` instead of `post`, and let the class based view handle the form instantiation. But you may find it easier to use a regular function based view instead.